# Drop to root in Ubuntu 20 Recovery is disabled

Tags: grub2, root, cisco, rescue-mode

Cisco Modeling Labs uses Ubuntu 20 for its base OS which I recently purchased for the Cisco learning center. I am installing it on a bare metal server, and I need to drop to root in order to mount a USB drive that contains more files required for the CML 2.4 to work properly.  However, when I get to the Recovery menu and select drop to root, I receive a notification that says, "press enter for maintenance or CTRL + D to continue".  When pressing enter the command line flashes and nothing happens.  Seems that this selection has been disabled by Cisco.  Is there a way to bypass the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you can drop into the root:

1. Reboot your device
2. During Grub boot menu click on 'Advanced options for ubuntu'
3. Highlight recovery mode
4. Click 'e' to edit the menu
5. Edit the line in-front of linux and add `init="/bin/bash"`

```
linux         /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=.. rw init="/bin/bash"
```

6. And click ctrl-x to boot